# How to set custom headers in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

JAVA developer send me data in headers. I take it this way

```
$_SESSION["HTTP_COUNTRYNAME"];
```

How to make response back with headers?  It tried `header("countryname: USA");` but php `function headers_list` doesn't show it.

Answer (score 39):

```
header('countryname: USA');
print_r(headers_list());

Array ( [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.0 [1] => countryname: USA )
```

...works for me.

Are you sure you haven't output anything before it? You cannot set headers after you've started printing text. Use `headers_sent()` to see if the headers have already been sent (that is, if you've already output something).

Answer (score 1):

in server file add
`header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: custom_header_name");`
in request for example AJAX add add `custom_header_name` and `value`
for example

`$.ajax({ url:your_url_to_server, method:'POST', data:dat, headers:{ "token_name":"19980", }, dataType:'json', success:(data)=>{ console.log(data) }        })`

then at server side you can access the value of the header by using
`$_SERVER['HTTP_CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME'];`
i hope this also works for you...