# Accept a user name from an HTTP header

Tags: http-headers, alfresco

i'm triying integrate my web with alfresco, i followed this doc: [SSO alfresco](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/auth-alfrescoexternal-sso.html), but can't understand how alfresco can accept a user name from an HTTP header.

I use the plugin Modify header and added a new row with `'name: value'` and works fine, but what i need to implement in my web for do the same that the plugin? thx!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add a name: value [Duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299977/how-to-set-custom-headers-in-php)

header('name: value');
print_r(headers_list());